# CountVectorizer: transform method returns multidimensional array on a single text line

Tags: python, python-2.7, text, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

Firstly, I fit it on the corpus of sms:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
clf = CountVectorizer()
X_desc = clf.fit_transform(X).toarray()
```

Seems to works fine:

```
X.shape = (5574,)
X_desc.shape = (5574, 8713)
```

But then I applied transform method to the textline, as we know, it should have (, 8713) shape as a result, but what we see:

```
str2 = 'Have you visited the last lecture on physics?'
print len(str2), clf.transform(str2).toarray().shape
```

> 52          (52, 8713)

What is going on here? One more thing - all numbers are zeros

Comment: what is `str1` in `clf.transform(str1)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You always need to pass an array or vector to `transform`; if you just want to transform a single element, you need to pass a singleton array, and then extract its contents:

```
clf.transform([str1])[0]
```

Incidentally the reason that you are getting a 2-dimensional array as output is that the a string is actually stored as a list of characters, and so the vectoriser is treating your string as an array, where each character is being considered as a single document.